# Spacing for underline/border - setting a specific width

Tags: html, css, uinavigationbar

I am creating a navigation menu in which has a specific active state. 
Essentially, its an underline, but with greater spacing and a specific width. So i have begun creating this navigation with a border-bottom attribute and a height. This solves the spacing underneath the navigation and the line, however, how can i set the width of the border underneath the writing so it appears like so:

[image: Home navigation]

[image: Admin navigation]

Essentially i have this:

```
<nav class="nav" role="navigation">
        <ul id="main-menu" class="pos-ul clearfix">
            <li class="first item"><a href="/" class="active">Home</a></li>
            <li class="item"><a href="/administration.html">Administration</a>        
</li>

.nav > ul > li {
position: relative;
float: left;
margin-left:19px;
font-size: 20px;
line-height: 66px;
color:#fff;
font-family:FrutigerLTPro-Roman;
font-weight:normal;
height:46px;
border-bottom:2px solid #fff;
}
```

which works, except for the width of the line? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want This?

```css
nav > ul > li {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 19px;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 66px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: FrutigerLTPro-Roman;
  font-weight: normal;
  height: 46px;
}
.nav > ul > li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #f00;
}
.nav > ul > li a.active:after {
  content: "";
  height: 2px;
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  left: 25%;
  right: 25%;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav" role="navigation">
  <ul id="main-menu" class="pos-ul clearfix">
    <li class="first item"><a href="/" class="active">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="item"><a href="/administration.html">Administration</a> 
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pseudo elements which can be customised as desired.

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.nav > ul > li {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 19px;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 66px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: FrutigerLTPro-Roman;
  font-weight: normal;
  height: 46px;
}
li.active::after,
li:hover::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 5ch;
  height: 4px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav" role="navigation">
  <ul id="main-menu" class="pos-ul clearfix">
    <li class="first item"><a href="/" class="active">Home</a>

    </li>
    <li class="item active"><a href="/administration.html">Administration</a> 
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```